# React js console array element undefind

Tags: json, reactjs, getjson

I try print this

```
console.log(location_list.all_list[3]);
console.log(location_list.all_list);
```

but have "undefined" in 1 case.
What is not right?

[image]

some more code:

```js
    var items = [];
    
    $.getJSON( "js/location_list.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push(key=val);
        });
    });
    
    this.all_list = items;
```

Conclusion: 
such assignments can not be used in "getJSON"

> this.all_list = items;

Comment: what is value of `location_list`?

Comment: console.log(typeof location_list); // object

Comment: you provided only 2 lines of code and ask what happen, we hardly answer

Comment: no, it is 115, 116 and 117 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i give you the idea

use call back technique

change definition of `list_load`, add `cb`

```
list_load : function(cb){
    var self = this;
    self.all_list = [];
    $.getJSON( "js/location_list.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            self.all_list.push(key=val);
        });
        cb()
    });
},
```

then

```
location_list.list_load(function(){
    console.log(location_list.all_list[3]);
    console.log(location_list.all_list);
    console.log(typeof location_list);
});
```

Comment: How do I do it right, without crutches? Is this possible?

Comment: with **ajax** you need to deal with **asynchronous**, and call back technique is the better way

Comment: 1 more question. Why is it wrong to do so in getJSON?  this.all_list.push(val);  Thanks!

Comment: ok i updated `list_load` for you, you should learn more about **function's this** from [this  - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), you can't use `this` inside call back function directly

Answer (score 0):

base on this code:

```
    var items = [];
    $.getJSON( "js/location_list.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push(key=val);
        });
    });
    this.all_list = items;
```

it looks like because of **asynchronous**

statement in retrieve event

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push(key=val);
});
```

you call `console.log(location_list.all_list[3]);` before retrieve event happen

```
console.log(location_list.all_list); => []
console.log(location_list.all_list[3]); => 'undefined'
```

you need to check length of `all_list`

```
if(location_list.all_list.length > 3) console.log(location_list.all_list[3]);
```

Comment: The tricky part is that when printing `all_list`, Chrome will change the printed value when the contents are loaded.

Comment: But in console output length: 8, why?

Comment: @МаргаритаКорнилова You are assigning `this.all_list = items;` before the request actually happens, you should do it inside the completion handler of `$.getJSON`. What actually happens is that you assign an empty array, then you print the empty values, then your request happens and fills up the array and then Chrome updates your previous console log of `all_list` with the current value.